# Printing directly from PHP using printer_write() function

Tags: php, printing, xampp, pecl

I found a code printing directly from PHP:

```
$printer = "cups-pdf";
$ph = printer_open($printer);
if ($ph) {
    $content = "Hello World...";
    printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
    printer_write($ph, $content);
    printer_close($ph);
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect...";
}
```

I'm trying to test it using XAMPP on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But it gives me an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/test.php on line 4`
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Install the PECL extension. Ah, and Printer is not available for Linux, it's a [Windows-only extension](http://php.net/manual/fa/refs.utilspec.windows.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to install the [Printer](https://pecl.php.net/package/printer) extension as it is [Windows-only](http://php.net/manual/fa/refs.utilspec.windows.php). There is no `config*.m4`(for Unix-like systems) file in [the source](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/printer/trunk/), only `config.w32`(for Windows).

It is also written in the PECL package description:

> Printer allows drawing (text, lines, ellipse, paging, etc.) and spool
>   controlling operation using a printer device on Windows.

Comment: Is there any other possible ways to test the printing code? Myself using above code in one of my web application and wanted to test it before writing the complete logic.

Comment: @mpsbhat, whether test it on a virtual machine (VirtualBox, QEMU, etc.), or port the extension to Linux

Comment: @mpsbhat, I mean you can run a Windows OS on Linux using a virtualization software such as Virtualbox, QEMU, etc. Otherwise, you'll have to port the Printer extension to Linux. I don't know any other way.