# Printing documents directly from PHP web application

Tags: php, printing

As a continued part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337700/printing-directly-from-php-using-printer-write-function), myself configured php_printer in windows using WAMP server (32 bit) and canon printer. It worked fine and the code prints the document. My current code is

```
 $printer = "My Canon Printer Name";
    $ph = printer_open($printer);
    if ($ph) {
        echo "Connected";
        $content = "Hello World...";
       // printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
       $pw = printer_write($ph, $content);
       if($pw) {
       echo "Printed";
       }
        printer_close($ph);
    } else {
        echo "Couldn't connect...";
    }
```

Now how can I print in similar way where my application is hosted in linux cloud server say, and i can open my screen in client PC through a browser with link http://myapplication.com/print-screen which having a button to invoke the printing job.